# How do I sort my columns so that they match the order of rows in a different dataframe?

Tags: r, sorting

Thanks to stack I am able to sort this dataframe, first according to "status", then by "ID", which looks like:

```
>pheno
  ID             status
1 patient19      0
2 patient21      0
3  patient7      1
4 patient10      1
```

(Code to make the pheno df):

```
ID = c("patient19", "patient21", "patient7", "patient10")
pheno = as.data.frame(ID)
pheno$status = c("0", "0", "1", "1")
row.names(phenodf) = pheno$ID
```

But now I have a second data frame in which the IDs are now the column titles, and these need be sorted so that it matches the order they're in with the pheno df. How can I do this?

```
>genes
gene     patient7 patient21 patient19 patient10
ABC      1.5       2.3       3.3       4.4
A2B      2.5       1.3       3.1       2.3
DE5      3.5       3.3       3.4       1.4
ZXY      4.5       4.3       3.6       5.1
```

(Code to make the genes df):

```
patient7 = c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5)
genes = as.data.frame(patient7)
genes$patient21 = c(2.3, 1.3, 3.3, 4.3)
genes$patient19 = c(3.3, 3.1, 3.4, 3.6)
genes$patient10 = c(4.4, 2.3, 1.4, 5.1)
row.names(genes) = c("ABC", "A2B", "DE5", "ZXY")
```

And this is how I need the genes df to look:

```
genes     patient19 patient21 patient7 patient10
ABC       3.3       2.3      1.5       4.4
A2B       3.1       1.3      2.5       2.3
DE5       3.4       3.3      3.5       1.4
ZXY       3.6       4.3      4.5       5.1
```

Comment: Use `match` to do this i.e. `pheno[c(1, match(df1$ID, names(pheno)[-1])+1)]`  assuming that the first data is 'df1' and second is 'pheno' and also assuming the 'ID' is `character` class

Comment: `genes[, pheno$ID]`

Comment: "pheno", the first dataset, is already the way I want it to be. "genes" is the 2nd dataset (I just now fixed the label for it), the one that needs to have the columns rearranged. Your code produced one column consisting of the IDs in the order I need, what do I do with that? I tried reversing it: a = genes[c(1, match(pheno$ID, names(genes)[-1])+1)]  but I get an error saying undefined columns

Comment: Would you mind telling me what all the "1"s do in your code akrun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `match`, the first argument is the labels you want to reorder, and the second argument is the desired order:

```
genes[, match(colnames(genes), rownames(pheno))]
```

The result of executing only `match` is:

```
3 2 1 4
```

which is just the order in which you need the columns of the `genes` dataframe, with respect to the order in the `pheno` dataframe.

Comment: Thanks! Your code worked for my example dataset but for some reason I had to switch the order in match() for my large dataset as follows: `genes[, match(pheno$ID, colnames(genes))]` - note that BOTH versions work for the test dataset, but the reversed version was needed for my large dataset for some strange reason...